# sorting a particular string of a certain format

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to sort this logically
Suppose I have a list of strings that have the follow elements

```
String[] myList = {"Spring 2013", "Fall 2009", "Fall 2010", "Spring 2012"};
```

I want to know how I can sort this where the result set would be
Fall 2009, Fall 2010, Spring 2012, Spring 2013

I appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: convert the string to a sortable from (dates, or strings in YYYY_MM format, etc).

Comment: you should show some efford....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the desired order is the natural (alphabetical) order, so you can use the [`Arrays.sort(Object\[\])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method.  If the desired order does not match the natural order, you can implement a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use the [`Arrays.sort(String\[\], Comparator<String>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

An example for the `Comparator` implementation (just to show how it could work):

```
public class SemesterComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private static final List<String> SEASONS = Arrays.asList("Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter");

    @Override
    public int compare(String one, String two) {
        String[] partsOne = one.split(" ");
        String[] partsTwo = two.split(" ");
        if (partsOne.length != 2 || partsTwo.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (!SEASONS.contains(partsOne[0]) || !SEASONS.contains(partsTwo[0])) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        // compare years
        int comparison = partsOne[1].compareTo(partsTwo[1]);
        if (comparison == 0) {
            // if years are equal: compare season
            comparison = SEASONS.indexOf(partsOne[0]).compareTo(SEASONS.indexOf(partsTwo[0]));
        }
        return comparison;
    }
}
```

But as already mentioned in the comments, it would be better to store the values in a format or class that is better sortable.

Comment: Im not sure I follow you. An example would be great.

Comment: compareTo automatically knows how to compare years?

Comment: `compareTo` uses the natural order per default. This is correct for years given with four digits. As said above, this is only an example. You could also parse an `int` from that string and compare that.

Comment: suppose I am comparing Fall 2012 to Winter 2012 how does your code determine which comes first?

Comment: Ah, I thought there would only be Fall and Summer (as there is in Germany). I’ll add that.

Comment: Can you explain this line to me.             comparison = SEASONS.indexOf(partsOne[0]).compareTo(SEASONS.indexOf(partsTwo[0]));
 I don't understand why this would work. Suppose it becomes "Spring".compareTo("winter") why would that work?

Comment: @user2879618 It would become `SEASONS.indexOf("Spring").compareTo(SEASONS.indexOf("Winter"))` which would become `0.compareTo(3)`. The `SEAONS.indexOf(...)` part converts the season to an integer that can be compared by its natural ordering.

Comment: so 0.compareTo(3) would then return -1 right? so if it returns a -1 that means that semester comes before right?

Comment: Would it still be the same if I were to do flip the switch compareTo and do say partsTwo.compareTo parts one?

Comment: Can it be alphabetical? Wouldn't `Fall 2013` come before `Summer 1969` alphabetically?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you can't reformat the string, you can write a custom comparator that implements that logic.  Your [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) would call split to separate the semester and year.  Then it can compare the year first followed by the custom month/semester logic.

You can call Collections.sort or Arrays.sort with a list and your custom comparator.

Comment: I already know how to compare the year, it is the comparing the semester part that is confusing me

Comment: There are a finite set of seasons that it could potentially be, no? (Fall, Summer, Spring, Winter) Just write a comparator that knows which order you want them to be in.

Comment: You can just use an if statement.  There are between two and four semester names depending on where you go to school.  You can just write if statements to compare them and return the first one.  Or you can be more complex and store them in an array and loop through it.  I'd just use the if statement.  For two semesters: It returns 0 if the semesters are the same.  Else -1 if the first one is "Fall".  Else 1.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky I think I understand what you mean but how does that cover suppose I am comparing the Summer to Spring?

Comment: @user2879618 If the years are the same, Summer > Spring because the summer semester happens later in the year. If the years are not the same you shouldn't even be comparing the semesters because the year comparison decides the result.

Comment: Forget about code for a minute.  Think about the rules.  Does Summer come before or after Spring?  (It would depend on your school.)  The substitute in the rules I gave.  Another alternative is to write 3 if statements to convert the semester name to a number 1 = Fall, 2 = spring, etc.  Then you can just subtract the #s as your comparator result.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the the season name such as "Spring" and "Fall" are "less significant" than the year,

Also that the seasons are not to be sorted alphabetically, but as winter, spring, summer, fall (I assume?).

So if you convert "Fall 2010" to "20104" and "Spring 2013" to "20132" then you can sort them as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how a [Comparator#compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) function might look like:

```
int compare(String o1, String o2) {
   // null values always prioritized
   if (o1 == o2) return 0;
   if (o1 == null) return -1;
   if (o2 == null) return 1;

   String[] parts1 = o1.split(' '); // e.g. ["Fall", "2012"]
   String[] parts2 = o2.split(' ');

   // invalid data, just throw some nonsense ordering out
   if (parts1.length != 2 || parts2.length != 2) {
     return parts2.length - parts1.length;
   }

   // have winner, 4 digit years can be compared lexicographical
   var yearCompare = parts[1].compareTo(parts[2]);
   if (yearCompare != 0) {
     return yearCompare;
   }

   // map term names to orderable values
   String[] termWeights = { "Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter" };
   var term1 = termWeights.indexOf(parts1[0]);
   var term2 = termWeights.indexOf(parts2[0]);

   // invalid terms prioritized
   if (term1 == term2) return 0;
   if (term1 == -1) return -1;
   if (term2 == -1) return 1;

   return term2 - term1;
}
```

Of course, I've not tested this at all. YMMV :)

Here is another alternative approach (based on a comment):

```
// swap "TermName Year" to "Year TermName"
String prioritizeYear (String i) {
   return i.replaceFirst("^(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+)", "$2_$1");
}

// convert "TermName" to "TermValue"
String weightTerm (String i) {
   return i.replace("Spring", "1")
           .replace("Summer", "2")
           .replace("Fall", "3")
           .replace("Winter", "4");
}

int compare(String o1, String o2) {
   // null values always prioritized
   if (o1 == o2) return 0;
   if (o1 == null) return -1;
   if (o2 == null) return 1;

   String n1 = weightTerm(prioritizeYear(o1));
   String n2 = weightTerm(prioritizeYear(o2));

   return n1.compareTo(n2);
}
```

Again, YMMV.